# Локальная копия web окружения как на удаленном хостинге

Tags: php, linux, apache, bash, apache2

Есть удаленный сервер на linux на котором стоит apache и php с доступом по ssh, и локальная машина на которой стоит linux mint.

Можно ли как то скопировать окружение удаленного сервера что бы локально разрабатывать на тех же настройках, и не было потом проблем с переносом сайта. Я понимаю что можно посмотреть какие пакеты установленные, и установить такие же и тд.

Может есть способ проще ? например сохранение настроек в баш скрипт "волшебной" командой и последующий запуск этого скрипта на локальной машине для разворачивания стека ?

Comment: Всё должно быть наоборот: вы должны не узнавать, что там на сервере установлено, а командовать серверу, что на нём должно быть установлено. У вас должен быть какой-нибудь механизм — например, Ansible-плейбук, — который знает всё о том, каким должно быть окружение, и может настроить его автоматически одной командой где угодно — хоть на сервере, хоть на локальной машине, хоть на виртуалке. А у вас изначально всё сделано неправильно, и, видимо, придётся посмотреть, что там установлено сейчас, и запихнуть в плейбук (к примеру)

Comment: (Кроме Ansible модно ещё заворачивать окружения в Docker-контейнеры, vagga/lithos и всё такое прочее, вариантов много, просто лично я использую именно Ansible)

Comment: Обычно для разработки не нужно много приложений - БД, язык разработки, ну и кэширование. Все они в большинстве работают одинаково на разных платформах, так что вам можно например взять OpenServer и работать с ним на локалке, настроив его предварительно.